# why does my app crashes with ipa while it runs with code on device?

Tags: iphone, ios

![enter image description here][1]My app crashes when i install it through itunes but when i run the same code through the code it doesn't crash on the device which is strange what might be reasons.The crash report doesn't give any clue of it.If it is a memory issue then it should crash even if run it through code?can anybody help me plzz.

the only hint it gives is as follows but i dont understand any thing from it :(

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
0x3a649348:  mov    r12, #328
0x3a64934c:  svc    #128

0x3a649350:  blo    0x3a649368                ; __pthread_kill + 32 thread 1: signal SIGABRT

0x3a649354:  ldr    r12, [pc, #4]             ; __pthread_kill + 24
0x3a649358:  ldr    r12, [pc, r12]
0x3a64935c:  b      0x3a649364                ; __pthread_kill + 28
0x3a649360:  .long  0x01ab6cc4                ; unknown opcode
0x3a649364:  bx     r12
0x3a649368:  bx     lr
```

Comment: Can you post the crash report, console logs when crash occurs?

Comment: Are you using different scheme for your ipa (probably release) and run (probably debug) ?
Schemes probably have different compile flags.

Comment: Add the crash log, the symbolicate crash log

Comment: Did you test it on every iOS version and device like iOS7,iOS 6? I dont know the exact cause of ur issue but same issue i was facing in the past 3-4 days. So reply may be I can help you..

Comment: it is not related to version.

Comment: in every iOS version it is crashing? Mine appplication run on iOS 7 but crashes on iSO6

Comment: how did u fix it? help me toooo .. i have edited my mail above plz see it.. and help out...